# Running WAS as a service

Tags: windows, websphere

What does it mean to run the WAS or WPS as a windows service? How is it different from running it as a java application? I have never had to run it as a service...so I am wondering if there is anything I am missing out on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading this and see if that helps you in understanding WAS as a windows service better

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1010_supauth/1010_supauth.html

HTH
Manglu

Comment: Thanks. The link describes how to set it up. I am wondering what is the difference between running WAS as service and running WAS as a javaw.exe app?

Comment: A Windows service has the same connotation has the Unix/Linux daemon, they run in the background and normally in a system security context (LocalSystem). Also, when you run a program using the command line and then you logout your session, the program will exit - on a Windows service / Linux daemon this doesn't happen.

Comment: Kaushik, I did see this in the article  that I referenced. A snip here for your quick reference: "There can be many reasons you might want to do this. Windows services typically live on each local machine and can be controlled by a local user or a domain user...."</snip>